# Deploying React Native Apps directly to devices for testing

Tags: ios, react-native, deployment, app-store

I'm looking into the best ways to deploy React Native apps to devices for testing. We don't want to put the app on the app store yet, but we do want the app to be downloadable to, say, an iPad.

What is the best way to do this? Do I need a testing platform or something like diawi? Or can I just put the file in an email and install it from there?

Comment: have you tried to put your app in testflight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS apps, test flight is the best way to go about this. https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: But there is a way to test ios app without upload it to the app store? (I mean without needing to pay?)

Answer (score 2):

Anyway for deploying an iOS application, you have to follow the standard developer portal process. If you already did that then all good to go otherwise you just need to follow [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3078-ios-code-signing-under-the-hood) tutorial.

Once you are done with code signing create a build using XCode Archive. This will generate .ipa file for you OR you can upload that to the testflight. If you want to skip testflight, there is one more tool available called [diawi](https://www.diawi.com).Diawi gives you a link instantly using which you can deploy the application on test devices.

Comment: With diawi could I distribute to as many users as I need - I see you can pay for more users in lots of 100, but would Apple restrict that - presumably you only get so any UUIDs? And would it expire?

Comment: Diawi will only allow registered devices. So that limit will remain up to 100 devices as apple allow you to register only 100 devices. And yes the link will expire in 48 hours. If you have such a requirement , then you should go with testflight.

Comment: If I do an ad hoc deployment - given that we only want employees to use the app - we would still only get 100 devices but we could use them indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

for Android , use internal testing and beta testing of google play 
check android documentation of internal testing [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213#internal_test)

for IOS,use [test flight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)